# Sharing sources between iframes

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe

My Angular app displays a lot of iframes at a time (16 max at a time to be exact), each containing HTML content - all of these iframes have jQuery imports using the script element, as well as some external font files that might differ between iframes.

Although performance is generally good, I noticed the browser launches GET requests to fetch jQuery and the fonts for every single iframe, which is pretty wasteful considering they all use the same jQuery version.

I could potentially stop using jQuery in these iframes, but the font files would still get fetched multiple times, which increases the latency when rendering them.

Any way I can get around this and possibly use a shared resource pool for my iframes?

Comment: Many of those duplicate requests should be being resolved from browser cache no?

Comment: Put these information into an Angular Service.